# Cannot delete some instances of model because of FK

Tags: python, django

> Python 3.6 and Django 1.11.7.

I've got two Models look like the following:

```
class User():
    name = models.CharField()
    ...

class UserInfo():
   user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT, primary_key=True, related_name='info')
```

I wanted to delete some user instance A, and I explicitly deleted user A's info. But when I tried to delete the user model `user.delete()`, I got the  `ProtecedError`:

```
ProtectedError: ("Cannot delete some instances of model 'User' because they are referenced through a protected foreign key: 'UserInfo.user'", <QuerySet [<UserInfo: UserInfo object>]>)
```

Then I tried to put the delete inside a try/catch looks like follows:

```
try:
    user.delete()
except ProtectedError:
    UserInfo.objects.filter(user=user).delete()
    user.delete()
```

But still got the same exception. What might went wrong in my operation?

Comment: `on_delete=models.PROTECT` is causing this. If you want to delete a user remove this argument. The default value is `CASCADE` which means if you delete the user it will also delete the `UserInfo` object linked to the user

Comment: I understand by removing `models.PROTECT` could solve this problem, but our project requires this to be `PROTECT`. And this did not happen every time when I tried to delete one user. Why is this happening?

Comment: You will net get the exception if you try to delete a `User` that has no link to a `UserInfo` object. If you want to delete `User` objects but keep the `UserInfo` objects then change to `on_delete=models.SET_NULL`. Although this might not work as you made the user field `primary_key=True`

Comment: I already deleted the related `UserInfo` before trying to delete the `User` object, but still got `ProtectedError `. I even check the database to make sure the `info` object had been gone.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a protect clause on the related objects:

```
on_delete=models.PROTECT
```

You can check it in the documentation on:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.on_delete

You have it pointed here:

*PROTECT[source]
Prevent deletion of the referenced object by raising ProtectedError, a subclass of django.db.IntegrityError.*

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `on_delete=models.PROTECT` on your `user` field. And run `manage.py makemigrations`

`ForeignKey` fields have a default value of `CASCADE` for the `on_delete` argument. This means that deleting the user object will cascade down and also delete the userinfo object linked to that user.

Looks like this is the behaviour you are looking for.

You can read more about this in the documentation [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#arguments)

Also note although `on_delete` has a default value fo `CASCADE` this argument will be required from Django 2.0.